# Angularjs select with ng-repeat not passing result as undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do a simple select and pass it to a console.log() in the controller. For some reason it results in "undefined". What am I doing wrong here?

Data:

```
    $scope.selectList = [
    {UpdateId : 1, Title:'A'},
    {UpdateId : 2, Title:'B'},
    {UpdateId : 3, Title:'C'}
];
```

View:

```
<form name="MyForm"><select name="RPSelection" ng-model="RPSelection"
 ng-options="selected.UpdateId as selected.Title for selected in  
 selectList"/>
<button ng-click="goToRosterProduction(RPSelection)">Select</button></form>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.goToRosterProduction = function () {
    console.log($scope.RPSelection)
}
```

Comment: need more details with more code

Comment: Hi Ramesh, Not sure what more you need.The select is pretty complete. The only thing missing is a button calling the method: goToRosterProduction(). Not passing anything in there As I'm call in $scope.RPSelection in the controller. No dependencies on this. What more would you need?

Comment: What is the vales for `selectList`?

Comment: Where you're calling `goToRosterProduction` function ?

Comment: add select close tag and name attribute :)

Comment: Vineet, I am calling it from the form in the view. Just added that so you can see.

Comment: Ramesh, The select is using ng-options and has no closing tag. I added a name value as well, but that does not make a difference in the results. Appreciate you guys looking at this.

Comment: Hi Jeeva, I tried both but still resulted in undefined.

Comment: Actually your code works for me. I did't change anything. it's working good for me.

Comment: Can I see your full controller code, with implementation?

Comment: Ramesh, really? That is so strange.

Comment: Yes, Your code works soo good for my system. I will ready to prepare fiddler result

Comment: Hi my guess is that you are fetching the data somewhere from the backend trough a service call or $http. Is this the case and did you just add the data so we know what the service returns ?

Comment: See my demo on fidler. it's working good

Comment: Hi Arno, correct. I found where it was an issue me calling the data as $scope.RPSelection.Id when I should have been simply calling the result $scope.RPSelection. This is now working for me.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sometimes it just needs a couple eyes and feedback to point us in the right direction!

Comment: @crowsfeet , actually i understood your exact problem. I think you got undefined error while click button without select dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't know the exact reason for this in angular js. But Here is the solution.

This case will occur sometime when we creating the model property dynamically from the view itself.

- If you declare the scope variable in the controller first and use it, you won't get the issue.
- Otherwise, if you want a dynamic scope variable, declare it as object in the view.

For example

```
<select ng-model="Obj.RPSelection" ng-options="selected.UpdateId as selected.Title for selected in selectList" />
```

In controller,

```
$scope.goToRosterProduction = function () {
    console.log($scope.Obj.RPSelection)
}
```

---

> I don't know the exact reason for this. But I had this issue many times. I guess if there is any complex html structure or if there is any issue in html structure, we are getting like this.

Answer (score -1):

### Problem

> Actually you got `undefined` error while click button without select dropdown. Because you did't set default selected value. So you got this problem. you need set default selected value in your controller.

### Solution

The problem was gone, if you set default value for the `RPSelection` object. like,

```
 $scope.selectList = [{UpdateId : 1, Title:'A'},
    {UpdateId : 2, Title:'B'},
    {UpdateId : 3, Title:'C'}];
    **$scope.RPSelection = 1;**
    $scope.goToRosterProduction = function () {
        alert($scope.RPSelection);// alert instead of console 
    console.log($scope.RPSelection)
}
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw8Kv/8/)